# How to test exceptions with assertThrows

Tags: unit-testing, lambda, exception, java-8, junit5

I have a function called "foo" which produces an ArrayList of strings. foo always returns a non-null array of size 2. When I try to reach an element which is out of the scope, I should get "IndexOutOfBounds" exception. There are two variations of the test method. The second one fails while the first one works just fine. What do you think is causing the second one to fail?

I've tried checking the exception using assertThrows but it didn't work as desired.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class fooClass {

    static ArrayList<String> foo (){
        ArrayList<String> arrayOfSize2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        arrayOfSize2.add("x");
        arrayOfSize2.add("y");
        return arrayOfSize2;
    }    
}
```

The following test chunk is working

```
@Test
void testFoo() {
    ArrayList<String> dummyArrayList = FooClass.foo();
    assertEquals("x",dummyArrayList.get(0));
    assertEquals("y",dummyArrayList.get(1));
    assertThrows(IndexOutOfBoundsException.class, () -> dummyArrayList.get(2));
}
```

But this one is not working

```
@Test
void testFoo() {
    ArrayList<String> dummyArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    dummyArrayList=fooClass.foo();
    assertEquals("x", dummyArrayList.get(0));
    assertEquals("y", dummyArrayList.get(1));
    assertThrows(IndexOutOfBoundsException.class, () -> dummyArrayList.get(2));
}
```

I expect the output of assertThrows to be `True` for the second code as well but the actual output is `Local variable dummyArrayList defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final`

Comment: Are you saying you are getting "must be final or effectively final" in the code you posted above, or the more "complex situation" you simplified from? As coded, it works perfectly for me, the exception is thrown, and the assertion succeeds.

Comment: You just revealed another puzzle to solve. It seems like I digressed from the objective while simplifying the problem. In the original code, I initialized the dummyArrayList and then assigned the return value of the function. I'll improve the post by adding a complete example.

Comment: Thanks for updating the code. Actually, Rahul B is correct (although he couldn't have known at the time he posted), the only problem here is that dummyArrayList is assigned twice, and then used in the lambda. I'm sure you can see that the first line is useless, right? Just combine those two lines so that dummyArrayList is not reassigned (which gives you your working test method) and you will be fine.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I can see that the first line of the second test chunk is pointless but since I'm expecting it to have the last assigned value, I don't completely understand the reason behind the failure. From my point of view: 
`ArrayList<String> dummyArrayList = FooClass.foo();` 
is equal to
`ArrayList<String> dummyArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
dummyArrayList=fooClass.foo();`

Comment: Caglar, yes, they are the same, but having it assigned twice means that the dummyArrayList **changes**. In order to use a variable declared outside in a closure, its reference can't change. Even if you know that it doesn't matter (because the closure will use the second instance assigned), the Java compiler will refuse because it requires it to be "final or effectively final."

Answer (score 2):

I think your approach is wrong, as it will also terminate exceptionally in the off-chance the `foo()` method returns a list of less than 2 elements, or `null`.

I'd test it in this order:

```
@Test
void testFoo() {
    ArrayList<String> dummyArrayList = FooClass.foo();
    assertNotNull(dummyArrayList);
    assertEquals(2,dummyArrayList.size());
    assertEquals("x", dummyArrayList.get(0));
    assertEquals("y", dummyArrayList.get(1));
}
```

[edit] or even simpler:

```
@Test
void testFoo() {
    ArrayList<String> dummyArrayList = FooClass.foo();
    assertIterableEquals(Arrays.asList("x", "y"), dummyArrayList);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your message. I'm actually using this procedure to test a complex situation. I wanted to simplify the question so people could understand. So, in this case, we can assume foo doesn't return a null collection or one smaller than size 2.

Comment: You probably want to use [assertIterableEquals](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.2.0/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html#assertIterableEquals(java.lang.Iterable,java.lang.Iterable)) instead of `assertEquals`.

Answer (score 0):

Variables used in lambda expression should be effectively final. the assertion is fine but the  lambda is complaining